# Accidentally disabled Local and Remote Access to Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, local

I have my DNS, DHCP server and site configured on the same server. I was about to block the remote access but accidentally disabled the local access also to the server. I am not able to login to the server now. Please help. We need to access this server asap because we are running one another important application on this server. I will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: how did you block access?

Comment: Console access?

Comment: Sounds like he set "deny login local" in Group Policy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Group Policy and target it to this server to "undo" your settings. If the Server is a DC as well, then remotely manage Group Policy to undo it.

Depending on how you did all this, maybe you are even able to undo it remotely by using the same tool you used to do it from a remote station. Many Microsoft tools can now be used from remote.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should always separate roles of servers, run them as virtual machines, and have regular snapshots available.

Correct the GPO that's causing the issue and then boot the server into safe-mode.  Override the local access setting in the registry AND clean out the group policy cache.  If that doesn't work, you might need to mount the drive under an offline registry editor.

Of course, this assumes that you have physical access to the server...